# How to download Google drive file using VBScript or cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, google-drive, vbscript

I am trying to download a video file from my google drive using VBScript or cmd. Named, WPR.avi and its size is 14MB.

I donno how to make it done successfully.

**Note :** I don't need wget or curl. I like to do it with self running program without help of any third party softwares.

Comment: you want to download a file from connected google drive storage to your PC?
or you want to download from google link url ?

Comment: google drive link URL bro

Comment: use PowerShell, there you will find similar tools like wget and curl without using any third party tools

Comment: You might be able to use the [bitsadmin](https://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

Go in developer mode in your browser in firefox this is done by using F12 then go to the console tab. Now when you download the file by hand you will see the console empty and a link will pop-up which you can use to download from the command line.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYPRq.png)